# You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False. Django-r-f

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, deployment, django-settings

I want to prepare the server for deployment and this is the setup.
settings.py is split into dev.py and prod.py

in settings.py at the bottom `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`
I also have tried `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

dev.py

```
    from ..settings.settings import *
    DEBUG = True
```

wsgy.py

```
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'movie_api.settings.dev')

    CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

When I import settings in the manage.py shell, the `settings.DEBUG = False` .. why?
How to make `wsgi.py` read the correct file?

Comment: If you have changed the name of your `settings.py` then you likely need to change `'movie_api.settings.dev'` to `'movie_api.dev'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the settings path in manage.py

Answer (score 1):

in django 3.2.6
i was able to resolve mine by updating my `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`